# javascript that shows or hides formatting at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I have a 'Div' that looks like this like this:

```
<div id="myContainer" contenteditable="true"> </div>
```

And inside this div, you will see that it contains this styled text:

This is **BOLD**

This is UNDERLINED

Ordered List:

1. **Bold**
2. NotBold

I have this javascript function that fires when I hit a button:

```
showSourceCode: function (e) {
    const $element = document.querySelector('#myContainer');
    var checkForHtml = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/(<([^>]+)>)/i);

    if (checkForHtml($element)) {
        this.isHTML = true;
    } else {
        this.isHTML = false;
    };

    if (this.isHTML) {
        $element.innerHTML = $element.textContent;
        this.isHTML = false;
    } else {
        $element.textContent = $element.innerHTML;
        this.isHTML = true;
    }
},
```

When I click it the first time, it shows me the source code correctly(which is what I want):

```
This is <span style="font-weight: bold;">BOLD</span><div>This is <span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">UNDERLINED</span></div><div><br></div><div>Ordered List:</div><div><ol><li>Bold</li><li>NotBold</li></ol></div>
```

Now I want to be able to click the button again, and see the actual CSS applied, but instead I get this:

```
This is &lt;span style="font-weight: bold;"&gt;BOLD&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div&gt;This is &lt;span style="text-decoration-line: underline;"&gt;UNDERLINED&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;Ordered List:&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;Bold&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;NotBold&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Is there a way to fix it so that it does this:

- If the content is already styled, show the source code
- If the content is showing the source code, then show the styled text

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the div to the test for html instead of its text
`checkForHtml($element)` -> `checkForHtml($element.textContent)`

```js
var obj = {showSourceCode: function (e) {
    const $element = document.querySelector('#myContainer');
    var checkForHtml = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/(<([^>]+)>)/i);

    if (checkForHtml($element.textContent)) {
        this.isHTML = true;
    } else {
        this.isHTML = false;
    };

    if (this.isHTML) {
        $element.innerHTML = $element.textContent;
        this.isHTML = false;
    } else {
        $element.textContent = $element.innerHTML;
        this.isHTML = true;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="obj.showSourceCode.call(event,this)")>Click</button>
<div id="myContainer" contenteditable="true">This is <span style="font-weight: bold;">BOLD</span><div>This is <span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">UNDERLINED</span></div><div><br></div><div>Ordered List:</div><div><ol><li>Bold</li><li>NotBold</li></ol></div></div>
```

Comment: What if the function doesn't know what format that the text will be in before the button click?

Comment: It doesn't but it checks the format before it renders/de-renders it